# Setting D-Link Modem in "Bridge mode"

Tags: router, home-networking, bridging

I am trying to extend the wireless network in my house.

I have a cable modem attached to a D-Link DIR-635 wireless router. This works fine if I am in the part of the house near the router.

I have got a set of [dlan avmini](http://www.devolo.com/consumer/72_dlan-200-avmini_network-kit_product-presentation_1.html) adapters to connect to the router through the power cables.

I have connected one adapter to the wireless router and one to a PC. This works fine.

What I have done now is to get a second wireless router (same model as first). I want to connect the second wireless router to a avmini adapter. When I run the setup for the router, I get a message at the end that I cannot connect to the Internet.

I have read that it should be possible to solve this by putting the router in bridge mode, but I have not been able to find how to do this.

So how do I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wireless routers must be set in bridge mode to have several WLAN points act as one.

Or if that is not possible a cheat would be to set up the second WLAN router with a WLAN, disable DHCP on it and connect the wired LAN interface to the dlan adapter.

The first wireless router would then serve DHCP to its WLAN, to its LAN and by extension of LAN-DLAN to the LAN and WLAN of the second wireless router. The two WLANs can be named the same or named differently.

Note that you should always set WLAN's to free channels, so the two WLAN routers should use different channels and you may want to avoid default channels like 6 and 11 (and probably others).

Answer (score 2):

You need to turn the second router into an access point:

Turn DHCP off and set the router IP to below or above the existing available DHCP range. Change the channel so it's not overlapping with the original router. Plug the ethernet cable into one of the LAN ports, not the WAN port. Voila!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently bridge mode is 'hidden' if you will on these devices.

The workaround involves turning off page styles on the webpage to be able to view the additional feature.

Graphics and more included in the link below.

http://forums.dlink.com/index.php?topic=6388.0

Comment: Your link no longer works

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to give each access point a different IP, make all other wireless details the same EXCEPT the channel. Make the channel for each Access point different.

So SSID, and WPA2 and wireless key all the same, just change the channel on each. Give AP1 ip x.x.x.2 (assuming your router is x.x.x.1) AP2: x.x.x.3 and so on.

Your laptops and phones will connect to the one with the strongest signal.